# ASP.NET MVC 3 and validation attribute for dropdownlist with default value of 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, drop-down-menu, model-validation

What is the best way to throw a required validation error using a validation attribute with a dropdownlist that has a default value of 0?  If the value is 0, or the default value, I want the attribute to throw the error for my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can provide the `option label` <sup>[*Docs*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561.aspx)</sup> that will set the selected value to `0` if not specified other wise like @Iridio menttioned in his answer, anotate the view model property with `[Required]`

```
public class MyVieWModel
 {
   [Required]
   public int MyValue { get;set;}
   public SelectList MyValues {get;set;}
 }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.MyValue,Model.MyValues,"-- Select --")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RequiredAttribute on your ValueId

something like this

```
 public class MyVieWModel
 {
   [Required]
   public int MyValue { get;set;}
   public SelectList MyValues {get;set;}
 }
```