# MVC Model validate Selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Drop Down List, with the first `<Option>` being `value="0"` `text="Select a category"`.

How can I put a Validation on the model to ensure this happens? Required would always be true, because there is always a selected value. It just mustn't be `"0"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `[Required]` and `[Range]` attributes, e.g.:

```
[Required]
[Range(1, YOUR_MAX_VALUE)]
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

See the [Microsoft docs on MVC DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

you can provide the `option label` <sup>[*Docs*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703561.aspx)</sup> that will set the selected value to `0` if not specified other wise like @Iridio menttioned in his answer, anotate the view model property with `[Required]`

```
public class MyVieWModel
 {
   [Required]
   public int MyValue { get;set;}
   public SelectList MyValues {get;set;}
 }
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.MyValue,Model.MyValues,"-- Select --")
```

[*Refrence*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980939/asp-net-mvc-3-and-validation-attribute-for-dropdownlist-with-default-value-of-0)

Answer (score 1):

you can provide a range of value starting at 1:

```
[Range(1, 99999)]
public int MyValue { get;set;}
```