# .Net MVC validate Selected Item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

**How to do client-side validation to validate a selected item?**

I have a `DropDownList` in .Net MVC3 Razor with the user role information. The role can be `SuperAdmin(RoleId=1)`, `Operator(RoleId=2)` and `Viewer(RoleId=3)`.

Now I want to deprecate `Operator`. How to do client side validation so that when the user edits his user information, the page will show validation error if the role is `Operator`?

This is the UserModel:

```
// User Role Id    
public int RoleId { get; set; }

/// Supported user roles
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupportedRoles { get; set; }
```

View:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleId, Model.SupportedRoles)
```

The expected behavior is that, for a user with `Operator` role, when he edits his user information, he cannot save his changes unless he changes his role from `Operator` to other role.

I don't want to remove `Operator` from `SupportedRoles` for an `Operator` user because if we do so, then when an `Operator` user updates other fields but does not update role, most likely his role will be changed to a default role and the user is not aware of that.

I read the answers from [MVC Model validate Selected Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277804/mvc-model-validate-selected-item?lq=1). `RangeAttribute` does not work for my case because the `RoleId` for `Operator` is in the middle of other RoleIds.

Comment: Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[NotEqualTo]` to similar validation attribute (or you can write your own that implements `IClientValidatable`). You should also be generating the `SelectList` to exclude `Operator` if the user does not already have that role assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own validation attributes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

There is a nice blog for this: http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc

```
    public class MyListAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
            public override bool IsValid(object value)
            {
                    return value != null && (int)value != 2;
            }
    }
```

Comment: OP's question is how to get **client side validation** (and this code will not give client side validation)